# Closure library component + Closure templates

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, google-closure-library, google-closure-templates

When you add a *Closure Component* as a child of other component, they should be parent and son in the *DOM* also. This is actually a pretty useful constraint.

The thing is I have some complex *Closure Components* and it'd be preferrable to create their HTML using *Closure Templates* (soy). At some point I have a widget which has many items inside and there's a single checkbox a few levels down which should be another *Closure Component*. But given the above constraint, I can't add the checkbox component as a direct child of the widget.

A Closure Component can be as simple as `div` `DOM` element:

```
<div id='main-component'>
    <p>
        <input id='sub-component' type='checkbox' />
    </p>
</div>
```

The checkbox would be an inner component. But if I were using Closure Templates, **how could i render the whole HTML and afterwards set the checkbox as a distinct component?**

Comment: read about decorateInternal, and yes, addChild(component, false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child component has to be a descendant, not necessarily a child in the DOM, see for example documentation for method [`addChildAt`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_ui_Component.html). So it's ok to call addChild(child, false) in this case.

Additionally, you can override `getContentElement` method of the parent component to return the element to which child components should be added, in this case you can if necessary use addChild(child, true) instead of decorating.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I am not terribly familiar with soy templates, but I do know that you can call `goog.ui.Component.addChild` with the second argument (opt_render) set to false, which will add the component as a child but not try to render it directly inside. I've used this in the past to have non-direct parent-child relationships between components.

Example :

```
var main = new goog.ui.Component();
main.decorate(goog.dom.getElement('main-component'));
var sub = new goog.ui.Component();
sub.decorate(goog.dom.getElement('sub-component'));
main.addChild(sub, false);
```

If I encountered problems doing this, I can't remember them now, so it'd be worthwhile to look into.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my inquiry is about a component being nested 2 levels deep at least. In that case you can't call ```addChild```.

Comment: So just take out the `main.addChild(sub, false)`. Don't you already have 2 distinct components?

Comment: Sorry the delay. That seems to add the component under the other. As I read in Closure: The Definitive Guide (Michael Bolin), I found components implement goog.events.EventTarget, which means they should be DOM related also to keep artifitial and native events flowing consistently. Doing ```main.addChild(sub, false``` would relate the two components in a way the DOM is not structured. This is the reason of my question.